# Control browser redraw

Tags: javascript, performance, animation

Hi I have a task where I do some heavy JavaScript animation, and I reposition various items using a timer. Now once the timer goes off, I move the elements by going through them all and changing their CSS properties.

Is there someway I can change all the CSS properties at once and than redraw? Because if there's really a lot of elements the page gets a little laggy.

Ps: would css3 animation help here?
Pps: does image resolution influence the speed a lot?
Ppps: it's not a normal website so the animations are necessary

Comment: I think you should look around here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Very interesting, a shame it isn't standard yet!

Comment: I use Safari, and during animations it uses a faster/blockier image resizing method. And you may check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999680/why-doesnt-jquery-use-requestanimationframe