# jQuery requestAnimationFrame disable pause on losing browser focus

Tags: jquery, html, requestanimationframe

I am building a jQuery app using animation.

Currently the `requestAnimationFrame` API pauses the animating if I minimize my browser or change browser tab, then when I come back to my application it starts again.

Would it be possible to avoid this pause so the animation keeps running when I leave the current tab?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Support for `requestAnimationFrame()` was removed some time ago due to the very problem you describe (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999680/why-doesnt-jquery-use-requestanimationframe) and [bug #9381](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9381)). Chances are you just have to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the intended behaviour of `requestAnimationFrame`; to request a frame when the browser is focused on the tab that the script is running in. If you need an animation to be constantly running then you'll want to use `setInterval` instead.

```
var FPS = 30;
setInterval(function()
{
  draw();
}, 1000/FPS);
```